# CSS "display: inline-block" Refusing to break lines

Tags: css, debugging, block

I'm working on a project and I'm attempting to style a specific link type in the same way as Adi Palaz uses [here](http://www.adipalaz.com/linksbg.html) to define external links. I have my code set up the same as his but for some reason `display: inline-block` is overflowing the containing `<li>` element (which has a defined width) so that the list elements stack 2 side-by-side.

Can someone tell me how to go about forcing the link "The Mountain and the Mole Hill" at bottom of this demo, development page (http://dreamstarstudios.net/sandbox/philosimply/sliding_drawer.html) to break lines?  I thought inline-block was expressly for the purpose of have text that is displayed as a block level element yet still breaks lines.  The even stranger thing is that changing it to `display: inline` doesn't force a line break but rather just causes the text to overflow the defined width :(

**EDIT** My apologies for not explaining further.  If you look at this link (http://www.adipalaz.com/linksbg.html) you will see how this developer used `white-space: nowrap` (which is needed) to achieve the desired effect I'm going for.  What I really need to know is why it is working for him but not me.

Comment: I closed this question on OP’s request as it seems to be no longer relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove `white-space:nowrap;`

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Comment: My apologies for not explaining further.  If you look at this link (http://www.adipalaz.com/linksbg.html) you will see how this developer used `white-space: nowrap` (which is needed) to achieve the desired effect I'm going for.  What I really need to know is why it is working for him but not me.

Comment: His method imposes to not break lines. It isn't possible in your case so I guess your links should be block instead of inline.

Comment: I know, I thought the same as you when I first looked at his tutorial.  But look here: http://drm.st/8nNU ... the subject of the whole tutorial is keeping the correct styling even when the line breaks.

Comment: So isn't inline-block enough for supporting IE?

Answer (score 0):

in your style sheet 'line 206' you are setting the width, it is doing exactly what you are telling it to do, you will need to make it wider or add `clear: both;` to the `li`.

Comment: I need them to stack in Left // Right alternating order the way they are right now, so the defined width is necessary.  This is an example of what I need - http://www.adipalaz.com/linksbg.html.  He has a defined width on his container, yet the behavior of the link is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

You've set `white-space:nowrap` on this link. That's why it won't break.

Comment: My apologies for not explaining further. If you look at this link (adipalaz.com/linksbg.html) you will see how this developer used white-space: nowrap (which is needed) to achieve the desired effect I'm going for. What I really need to know is why it is working for him but not me